# unable to install NanoPlot

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

while installing NanoPlot with pip I got the following Error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Wolfram\Documents\kurse\python\herdecke\kurs2024-04-03_H9\virtuelle Umgebung\v_herdecke\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Wolfram\Documents\kurse\python\herdecke\kurs2024-04-03_H9\virtuelle Umgebung\v_herdecke\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' get_requ
es_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Wolfram\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqlvgtqde'
     cwd: C:\Users\Wolfram\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v_nmqf_f\pysam_da81f83b6f9548f8b7475b95fa885074
Complete output (34 lines):
# pysam: cython is available - using cythonize if necessary
# pysam: htslib mode is shared
# pysam: HTSLIB_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=None
Der Befehl "." ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Der Befehl "." ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

Error meaning: `The command "." is wrong spelled or can't be found`.

another trial inside of Thonny resulted in the same Error

Comment: Can you translate these errors into english perhaps? 
Der Befehl "." ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder

Comment: Translation: The command "." is wrong spelled or can't be found

Comment: The error is what `cmd` complains of if you enter something that cannot be run. It looks as if somebody tries to run a shell script from `cmd`. E.g. `./my_app.exe` will throw this error while `my_app.exe` will succeed. Maybe try with `git-bash`, `cygwin`, whatever...